# Can the phrase "if you please" be used to introduce requests?

Tags: phrases

Can the phrase "if you please" be used to introduce requests? Example:

> If you please, could you tell me his whereabouts?

Comment: What does your research show?

Answer (score 1):

While it technically applies as a polite request, it doesn't really apply well in this situation because "If you please..." is almost always used as another way of saying "If you would like". Regardless of whether or not the person would like to tell you, you are placing a requested demand to know something. "Could you please tell me his whereabouts?" would be more fitting in this situation.

"If you please" also is more applicable with physical actions rather than verbal interactions. For instance, "Come this way, if you please." where in this example, the person isn't making a request, but instead inviting you to physically come with them.